# Change gallery images in wordpress or wix when user clicks

Tags: wordpress, velo

First question from me here :)

I need to find a solution for an image gallery on two columns when the user changes images when clicks. I put an example below.
http://officekgdvs.com/projects/#office-45
The client wants to work with Wix or WordPress.
Many thanks and have a great year

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the community. First of all i would like to point out the [question's guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In this case you're asking for a complete solution while the community is actually more based on asking specific questions. Like what have you tried already? Do you maybe have any code examples or some stub code to show to the community?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this on Wix using repeaters, the Content Manager, and the onClick event handler.